# Time Validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm working on time and validation in javaScript, in this validation the time is entered by the user and validate through the conditions, date gets validate easily but time is not getting validate my code is :

HTML

```
<input type="date" id="date-input" required />
<input type="time" id="stime" required/>
<input type="time" id="etime" required/>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Javascript is

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
//date validation ------------------------------------
var date = new Date($('#date-input').val());
  var today = new Date();
  var date1 = date.getDate();
  var date2 = today.getDate();
  if(date1 < date2){
  alert("please fill valid date");
  }
//-------------------time validation-----------------------
var t1 = new Date($('#stime').val());
var t2 = new Date($('#etime').val());
var time1 = t1.getHours();
var time2 = t2.getHours();

if(time1==time2){
alert("Please Make Differrnce between time");
}
 if (time1 < 9 || time2 > 17 ){
alert("Please fill time between 9:00 to 17:00");
}
```

Comment: Try consoling the values of t1 and t2 and then do the further operations.

Comment: You can add jquery ui library and use datepicker it provides date difference.

Comment: You should use momentjs to handle dates and time.

Comment: @ashu p i need time validation

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5fejH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the time in miliseconds and compare them in miliseconds to validate the hours.

```
var t_one= $('#stime').val();
var t1 = t_one.split(":");
var t_two = $('#etime').val();
var t2 = t_two.split(":");
var time1 = (+t1[0] * (60000 * 60)) + (+t1[1] * 60000);
var time2 = (+t2[0] * (60000 * 60)) + (+t2[1] * 60000);
```

You can see it working here.

https://jsbin.com/xagisikado/edit?html,js,console,output